# Open copy data from multiple files into one sheet- shortcut

Tags: vba, copying

Hoping you can help I only know basics and am trying to see of there is an easy way to repeat a process in a vba than retyping.

Basically I need to copy data from multiple files into one file. The files I want to copy are all in different sub folders.

Here is what I have but as you can see I'm just copying the code and changing the file location to complete the task which works but just wondering if easier way as there are multiple files which are in different locations.

```
Sub Disconnections()

'
' Disconnections Macro
'
SheetName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
On Error GoTo AddNew
Sheets(SheetName).Activate
Exit Sub
AddNew:
Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName '
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\My Documents\Customer 1\Customer 1 Data List"
    Sheets("Disconnections").Select
    Sheets("Disconnections").AutoFilterMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Disconnections.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Windows("Connection List - Abel & Cole.xls").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\My Documents\Customer 2\Customer 2 Data List"
Sheets("Disconnections").Select
Sheets("Disconnections").AutoFilterMode = False
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Disconnections.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Windows("Connection List.xls").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Is this possible.

Thank you

***Update****

I'm now getting run time error 438 - object doesn't support this property or method. I guess I'm missing something or edited the data wrong. Can you please let me know what's wrong

```
Sub Disconnections()

'
' Disconnections Macro
'
SheetName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
On Error GoTo AddNew
Sheets(SheetName).Activate
Exit Sub

AddNew:
Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName '

Dim x As Integer
Dim numFolders As Integer
numFolders =       WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Column(1))

For x = 1 To numFolders
Dim i As Integer, NoCustomers
NoCustomers = 3
For i = 1 To NoCustomers
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\My Documents\Customer 1 \ Customer 1 Data List
    Sheets("Disconnections").Select
    Sheets("Disconnections").AutoFilterMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Disconnections.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   Windows("Customer 1 Data List.xls").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Next i
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop like this:

```
Dim i As Integer, NoCustomers

NoCustomers=99
For i = 1 To NoCustomers
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\My Documents\Customer "&i&"\Customer "&i&" Data List"
    'do copy-paste-thing
Next i
```

Also, you could get rid of those "select"-lines that look like this:

```
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sheet to list all the folders that you want and create a loop for simplify the code. You can use a integer variable and CountA in the folders column for obtain the number of loops that you need to use. If you don't understand I could write an example in an hour.

**Edit:**

The example is something like this.

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim numFolders As Integer

numFolders = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheetWithFoldersList").Column(1))

For x = 1 to numFolders
'enter the code for looping'
Next x
```

Comment: Thank you, ive never used integer variables could you please provide an example I really appreciate your help

Comment: I edited my answer with a little example. Remember create our use the second sheet with the folders links.

Comment: I've updated my original question - am getting a run time error now:(

Comment: Set NoCustomers out off the loops, like the other declarations. This part `C:\My Documents\Customer 1 \ Customer 1 Data List` must be in the folders list, no? Now you must write `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x)` and continue with the script. However I think that won't work but we could see what's going on better than now.